# Easiest way to create a Facebook application

Tags: facebook, tabs

I need to create a simple tab page with custom content inside. How on earth I can get there the shortest and easiest way? Maybe I want to track the users who liked the page, but that's not compulsory. I just want to create a tab-page, which can integrate into a page and shows some custom content.

I have created an application at Facebook, the thing is, I don't know where to head from here, to include some content in the innards of that page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page tab or any application on facebook can be and usualy is considered a normal website.  You'll need the same things that you would if you wanted to create a website.  You'll need a server, some storage space, possible a database (if you want to store date about/for your users).
There are ways to get started for free - lots of free hosting companies out there. You can start your search [here](https://www.google.com/?q=free+web+hosting)
Facebook also has links to [develop applications in a cloud system].

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want a static FBML tab. It is hard to find on Facebook, however it is possible to find a link like [this](http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=9b6c3032a5f661005f6c5a11f8c57377&pages). If you are logged in to Facebook then it should take you to a page where you can add a static FBML tab to one of the pages you administer. After that you can customize the tab content from page settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of facebook apps, but one of them is just a canevas app.
So you ca include an external web page in a facebook page. It's pretty similar to a frame i think.

You can find inforations here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#canvas